# Querying SharePoint 2010 Search -- FAST

Tags: search, fast-search, web-services

I have constructed a simple web application following the MSDN walk-through as a guide:

Here is the Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub btnQuery_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnQuery.Click
    Try
        Dim lcQueryServices As New QueryWebServiceProxy.QueryService()
        lcQueryServices.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        'lblErrors.Text = GetXMLString().Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;") 'To Test that XML String is rendered correctly
        Dim lcQueryResults As System.Data.DataSet = lcQueryServices.QueryEx(GetXMLString())
        grdResults.DataSource = lcQueryResults.Tables("RelevantResults")
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblErrors.Text = ex.ToString()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function GetXMLString() As String
    Dim lsQueryXML As XElement = <QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query'>
                                     <Query>
                                         <SupportedFormats>
                                             <Format revision='1'>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document:Document</Format>
                                         </SupportedFormats>
                                         <Context>
                                             <QueryText language='en' type='FQL'>
                                                 <%= GetFQLString() %>
                                             </QueryText>
                                         </Context>
                                         <ResultProvider>FASTSearch</ResultProvider>
                                         <Range>
                                             <Count>10</Count>
                                         </Range>
                                     </Query>
                                 </QueryPacket>
    Return lsQueryXML.ToString()
End Function

Private Function GetFQLString() As String
    Dim lsFQLString As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder("string(""")
    'lsFQLString.Append(txtQuery.Text)
    lsFQLString.Append("test"", mode=""and"")")
    Return lsFQLString.ToString()
End Function
```

I am receiving the following error when attempting to query the web service:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) at FQLTest1.QueryWebServiceProxy.QueryService.QueryEx(String queryXml) in C:\Users\nealcb\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Web Projects\FQLTest1\FQLTest1\Web References\QueryWebServiceProxy\Reference.vb:line 143 at FQLTest1._Default.btnQuery_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\nealcb\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Web Projects\FQLTest1\FQLTest1\Default.aspx.vb:line 15

Any recommendations?

Update 1.0 3/11/2011

I was able to move my testing to Powershell where I am able to make rapid changes to the query to see if I get any errors.  Here is what I found in the logs:

> 03/11/2011 15:27:51.88    w3wp.exe (0x126C)                           0x1274  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           g4hl    Medium      FastSearchGateway::GetQueryResult--Unrecognized Field Exception searching on QRServer: http://FastQuryServer:13287 -- Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Extended.Query.Query.UnrecognizedFieldException: Field Write not found in search results.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Extended.Query.Result.TextResultParser.ReadDocument(TextReader reader)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Extended.Query.Result.TextResultParser.ParseInternal(TextReader reader)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Extended.Query.Result.TextResultParser.Parse(Stream result)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Extended.Query.Http.AbstractUrlBasedSearchEngine.SearchInternal(IQuery query, IResultParser parser, String urlStr)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Extended.Query.Http.AbstractUrlBasedSearc...    6281e480-7d74-4026-87ca-f6a0b93983f9
>   03/11/2011 15:27:51.88* w3wp.exe (0x126C)                           0x1274  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           g4hl    Medium      ...hEngine.Search(IQuery query)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Gateway.FastSearchGateway.GetQueryResult(IQuery query)  6281e480-7d74-4026-87ca-f6a0b93983f9
>   03/11/2011 15:27:51.88  w3wp.exe (0x126C)                           0x1274  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           g4hk    Monitorable AbstractSearchGateway::Search--Exception when searching for string("buchan", mode="and"). Ex: Write 6281e480-7d74-4026-87ca-f6a0b93983f9
>   03/11/2011 15:27:51.88  w3wp.exe (0x126C)                           0x1274  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           g4i1    Monitorable FASTQueryInternal::Execute--Invalid Property Exception when trying to search FAST backend: Write    6281e480-7d74-4026-87ca-f6a0b93983f9
>   03/11/2011 15:27:51.88  w3wp.exe (0x126C)                           0x1274  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dk68    High        SearchServiceApplication::Execute--Exception: Write 6281e480-7d74-4026-87ca-f6a0b93983f9
>   0

Update 1.1 - Below is my Powershell Script I am using to test this.  In speaking with the team, we are leaning towards the property being a duplicate in the managed metadata service (I think).  I have verified that the FQL I am transacting is valid.  I have decided to run the same script (below) against my dev sharepoint server running on a VM.  I just need to get Search enabled first.

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "***" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "***", $pass
$web = New-WebServiceProxy "http://SearchWebService" -Credential $creds 
$lsQueryXML  = "<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query'><Query><SupportedFormats><Format revision='1'>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document:Document</Format></SupportedFormats><Context><QueryText language='en' type='FQL'>string(`"buchan`", mode=`"and`")</QueryText></Context><Properties><Property Name=`"WorkId`"/><Property Name=`"Rank`"/><Property Name=`"Title`"/><Property Name=`"Author`"/><Property Name=`"Path`"/><Property Name=`"Description`"/><Property Name=`"SiteName`"/><Property Name=`"CollapsingStatus`"/><Property Name=`"HitHighlightedSummary`"/><Property Name=`"HitHighlightedProperties`"/><Property Name=`"ContentClass`"/><Property Name=`"IsDocument`"/><Property Name=`"PictureThumbnailURL`"/><Property Name=`"Url`"/><Property Name=`"ServerRedirectedUrl`"/><Property Name=`"SpSiteUrl`"/><Property Name=`"docvector`"/><Property Name=`"fcocount`"/><Property Name=`"fcoid`"/><Property Name=`"PictureHeight`"/><Property Name=`"PictureWidth`"/></Properties><ResultProvider>FASTSearch</ResultProvider><Range><Count>10</Count></Range></Query></QueryPacket>"
$lcQueryResults = $web.QueryEx($lsQueryXML)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are searching for a Managed Property that doesn't exist in FAST. That's what the "*Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings*" and "*Unrecognized Field Exception searching on QRServer*" messages seem to indicate.

Follow the steps on my blog to [debug directly on the QR server](http://www.neilrichards.net/blog/?p=100). If you can't get an FQL query to work there, it isn't going to work on via powershell/c#. The QR server is a FAST interface accessible only while RDP'ed onto the FAST server, typically accessible via http://localhost:13280 (baseport + 280).

Consider using the [MOSSMan FAST Query Tool](http://fastforsharepoint.codeplex.com/) to help create the correct XML for your query.

Comment: Referencing your blog post, I am confident that my XML is adequate.  Looking through the logs, I have determined that the write field is apparently at fault.  I am trying to delete it, but it is proving stubborn.

Comment: The Write field refers to the Modified Date so I doubt you want to delete it. Coming back to the XML, if you paste it into the MOSSMan tool, does it return a result? 

What you might need to do is create and deploy a new Write field (in case yours somehow got deleted) or if it exists, make it queryable.

Comment: "Field Write not found in search results." seems to indicate the field is not queryable.

Comment: Neil, Would I use the search.asmx page for the Site URL in MossMan's FAST for SharePoint Query Tool?

Comment: I usually just point it at my search site (i.e. http://<myserver>/search

Comment: This is what I got when runninng the query in MossMan:

<ResponsePacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response">
  <Response domain="">
    <Status>ERROR_SERVER</Status>
    <DebugErrorMessage>Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.InvalidPropertyException</DebugErrorMessage>
  </Response>
</ResponsePacket>

Comment: Okay so for me, that seems to indicate that the xml is wrong. I've tried copying your xml snippet but I think something is getting lost in translation (it's hard to know if it's escaped properly when going to the FAST server). I suggest you add in all the properties via the MOSSMan tool manually, one by one, and see where its failing.

Comment: Also, this will sound really stupid but try converting all your properties to lower case.

Comment: Alright using Mossman's tool and adding/removing properties, I was able to get this working!  Thanks so much for your help Neil.

Comment: Glad to help you find a solution. If you can, please post your solution so others can benefit in the future. Cheers!